# Staging server does not recognize email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have created a email template named: `order_new_guest.html`.

This is placed in my custom theme `Magento_Sales/email` directory. On my **local dev server it properly overwrites magento standard email template**.

But on the staging server it does not find it and instead of that it uses the standard template.

Neither it is found in the loadable templates, when managing email templates in admin.

I have `redeployed static, recompiled` etc but still nothing.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the template file definitely there on the staging server? Has the cache definitely been cleared?

Comment: I had mistakenly excluded it from git and assumed it was there. Often the crap is behind the keyboard. :D